# How to name an attachment using DocumentGenerator

Tags: wolfram-cloud, templates

I want to use `DocumentGenerator` to send a PDF to someone else as an attachment.

**How can I name the attachment?**

It currently defaults to "current" and I would like to change it to a file name with a date extension eg. `"Weather_" <> DateString["ISODate"]`.

I would have thought I can use the option `DeliveryFunction->f` to define a function to do this but the documentation is not clear.

```
template = StringTemplate["Time: `time`\nCurrent temperature: `temp`"];
driver = <|"time" :> Now, "temp" :> AirTemperatureData[]|>;

co = CloudDeploy[
  DocumentGenerator[
   template,
   driver,
   DateObject[{_, _, 25}],
   DeliveryFunction -> {{"you@example.com"} -> "PDF"} (*change to your email*)
   ],
  "Test for SE"
  ]

TaskExecute[co]
```

Comment: I cannot run your code ... [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz0aP.png). Please provide a working code :-)

Comment: @Domen It works on my machine and on cloud. Can you try ```template = StringTemplate["Time: `time`"]; driver = <|"time" :> Now|>;```